Group by sum larger than aggregated column?
If I have eg a table as shown below:



ID
Threshold
Value




1
2
1


1
2
2


1
2
3


1
2
4


2
4
1


2
4
3


2
4
5



How could I use spark to obtain the following?



ID
Threshold
total_above_threshold




1
2
7


2
4
5



I have thought of a workaround where I create an additional column to flag out values below or equal the threshold, and aggregate the unflagged values. But does spark provide a good way (eg. window function?) that doesnt require creating additional columns?

Shouldn't be the total_above_threshold = 8 for ID = 1?

@VikasSharma sorry I think I wasn't being clear in my column name "total_above_threshold". My intention is to sum up only values above the threshold for each ID. Eg for ID 1, the threshold is 2, so records with values 1 and 2 are removed since i only want values above 2.

Thanks for clarifying - updated the answer.

No window function is needed - you can simply use groupBy as follows:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, sum

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data = [
    (1, 2, 1),
    (1, 2, 2),
    (1, 2, 3),
    (1, 2, 4),
    (2, 4, 1),
    (2, 4, 3),
    (2, 4, 5)
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["ID", "Threshold", "Value"])

result_df = (
    df
    .filter(col("Value") > col("Threshold"))
    .groupBy("ID", "Threshold")
    .agg(sum(col("Value")).alias("total_above_threshold"))
)

result_df.show()

# +---+---------+---------------------+
# | ID|Threshold|total_above_threshold|
# +---+---------+---------------------+
# |  1|        2|                    7|
# |  2|        4|                    5|
# +---+---------+---------------------+

